# Differences in centrality measures between igraph and tnet

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I'm trying to obtain centrality measures for a directed, weighted network.  I've been using the `igraph` and `tnet` packages in `R`.  However, I've discovered some differences in the results obtained using these two packages, and I'm a little confused about the cause of these differences.  See below.

```
require(igraph)
require(tnet)
set.seed(1234)

m <- expand.grid(from = 1:4, to = 1:4)
m <- m[m$from != m$to, ]
m$weight <- sample(1:7, 12, replace = T)
igraph_g <- graph.data.frame(m)
tnet_g <- as.tnet(m)

closeness(igraph_g, mode = "in")

         2          3          4          1 
0.05882353 0.12500000 0.07692308 0.09090909 

closeness(igraph_g, mode = "out")

         2          3          4          1 
0.12500000 0.06250000 0.06666667 0.10000000 

closeness(igraph_g, mode = "total")

         2          3          4          1 
0.12500000 0.14285714 0.07692308 0.16666667 


closeness_w(tnet_g, directed = T, alpha = 1)

     node closeness n.closeness
[1,]    1 0.2721088  0.09070295
[2,]    2 0.2448980  0.08163265
[3,]    3 0.4130809  0.13769363
[4,]    4 0.4081633  0.13605442
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Normalization, and also the order of the vertices might be different. I would draw a simple example and calculate closeness for that by hand, if you suspect one of them is wrong.

Comment: @Gabor Csardi thanks for your suggestions!  I had already tried using the normalization option in the `closeness` function from `igraph` without success, and had also already noticed that the order of the closeness scores was a little weird from the `igraph` `closeness` function.  As it turns out, the inconsistency was due to differences in how `igraph` and `tnet` treat the weights when calculating closeness.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After posting this question, I stumbled upon a [blog](http://toreopsahl.com/) maintained by Tore Opsahl, maintainer of of the `tnet` package.  I asked this same question of Tore using the comments on [this](http://toreopsahl.com/2010/04/21/article-node-centrality-in-weighted-networks-generalizing-degree-and-shortest-paths/) post of the blog.  Here is Tore's response:

> Thank you for using tnet! `igraph` is able to handle weights; however, the distance function in `igraph` expects weights that represent 'costs' instead of 'strength'. In other words, the tie weight is considered the amount of energy needed to cross a tie. See [Shortest Paths in Weighted Networks](http://toreopsahl.com/tnet/weighted-networks/shortest-paths/).

Thus, if you run the following code provided by Tore (which takes the inverse of the weights before passing them to `igraph`), you obtain equivalent closeness scores for both `tnet` and `igraph`.

```
> # Load packages
> library(tnet)
>   
> # Create random network (you could also use the rg_w-function)
> m <- expand.grid(from = 1:4, to = 1:4)
> m <- m[m$from != m$to, ]
> m$weight <- sample(1:7, 12, replace = T)
>   
> # Make tnet object and calculate closeness
> closeness_w(m)

     node closeness n.closeness
[1,]    1 0.2193116  0.07310387
[2,]    2 0.3809524  0.12698413
[3,]    3 0.2825746  0.09419152
[4,]    4 0.3339518  0.11131725

>   
> # igraph
> # Invert weights (transform into costs from strengths)
> # Multiply weights by mean (just scaling, not really)
> m$weight <- mean(m$weight)/m$weight
> # Transform into igraph object
> igraph_g <- graph.data.frame(m)
> # Compute closeness
> closeness(igraph_g, mode = "out")

        2         3         4         1 
0.3809524 0.2825746 0.3339518 0.2193116
```